# How to load a URL only if it exists in a batch file using curl for windows?

Tags: batch-file, curl

I am trying to shutdown a service running running locally by using URL like 'localhost:3502/shutdown' using curl.

I give curl 'localhost:3502/shutdown'. 
But I need to do this only if the service is still running. Else I should not.

I wanna do it in a batch file for windows.

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -p tcp -n -a | findstr /b /r /c:"  TCP[ ]*[0-9.]*:3502 " >nul && (
     curl http://localhost:3502/shutdown
)
```

I am not sure how you want to determine if the service is running. Maybe this can work. This code checks for existence of the listening port.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. It works. for /f %I IN ('curl -s -o abc.txt -w %{http_code} -I http://www.google.com') do call set  _responsecode=%I:~0,2% & if %_responsecode==200 echo "shutdown".